# Отправить данные авторизации tg в БД

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Имеется многостраничный сайт, куда требуется добавить авторизацию пользователей через Телеграм.

С установкой виджета вопросов не возникло, но я завис на этапе отправки данных в БД.

При установке виджета выбрал Redirect URL, где указал главную страницу сайта. После авторизации по нажатию на виджет в адресной строке указываются данные пользователя (id, username...), которые нужно отправить в БД.

Пример адресной строки после авторизации и редиректа пользователя:

```
000webhostapp.com/?id=1806256247&username=sdfsmdfom46
```

Каким способом можно получить эти данные из адресной строки, чтобы отправить их в БД?

БД создана через phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Каким способом можно получить эти данные из адресной строки, чтобы отправить их в БД?

Предложу такой вариант получения переменных из твоего УРЛ...

```js
let url = '000webhostapp.com/?id=1806256247&username=sdfsmdfom46'
url = url.split('/?')[1]
url = url.split('&')
const o = url.reduce((o, v) => {
  const a = v.split('=')
  o[a[0]] = a[1]
  return o
}, {})
console.log(o)
```

Comment: А саму ссылку пользователя можно перехватывать таким образом?

window.location.href;

Comment: @Timkekz, так я понял ты ту строку из `window.location.href` брал.